# Schedule a Jenkins job for future date

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have to schedule a Jenkins job  which runs every Day of the week, every Month in a year , every Day in a month **but after a specific date.**

I have used the below cron expression but it will trigger the job only on 1:00 pm for sept month only.

```
0 13 * 8 *
```

**I need to schedule it from Sept,01,2018 onward everyday at 1:00pm.**

Comment: Use https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Schedule+Build+Plugin, for trigger in future.

Comment: @3sky Good hint. You could post that as an answer for better visibility and some points.

Comment: Sure, why not :)

Answer (score 1):

If You want to trigger in future use: [Schedule Build Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/schedule-build/)

Answer (score -2):

0 0 13 1 1/1 ? *
For more information you can visit www.cronmaker.com
Thanks,
Sunny

Comment: This is not a point. The problem is how run job **after** specific date.